# Code not working even though I'm following exact tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

I'm following a tutorial and I've done it exactly the same step by step but the $ doesn't come up as it's own thing and the if margins statements give errors. I'm a bit confused as to where I'm going wrong?

Here is the YouTube video with timestamp for reference:
https://youtu.be/_oO4Qi5aVZs?t=2248

Comment: Isn't that just highlighting - something that's from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Also, the video is using backticks `` not single quotes `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use single quotes inside single quotes, you have to escape them but the video you mentioned is using [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which are used to escape strings, and do some other stuff.

> Template literals are literals delimited with backtick (`) characters, allowing for [multi-line strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings), [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) with embedded expressions, and special constructs called [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates).

```js
className={`font-poppins font-normal cursor-pointer text-[16px] ${index === navLinks.length-1 ? 'mr-0' : 'mr-10'} text-white`}>
```

Single quotes (what you used):

```js
className={'font-poppins font-normal cursor-pointer text-[16px] ${index === navLinks.length-1 ? 'mr-0' : 'mr-10'} text-white'}>
```